# подскажите новичку в css

Tags: css, css3

подскажите как убрать эти белые отступы margin и padding не помогают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких случаев существует нормализатор. Он сбрасывает дефолтные стили браузера. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ Рекомендую всегда подключать к вашим проектам. Это правильный подход для таких вот случаев.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй так:

```
html, body{
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: А лучше добавь  код к вопросу

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы меня выручили.

Comment: @SurikPozoyan :) Удачи в обучении

Comment: @SurikPozoyan «выручил» на этом сайте принято отмечать галочкой у ответа, который выручил :)

Answer (score 0):

Для лучшего контроля отступов, можете изначально сбрасывать `margin` и `padding` у всех элементов:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

`box-sizing` - это добавьте, чтобы проще было работать с размерами.

Подробнее про `box-sizing` почитайте [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).